# this.merge is not a function in ember 1.10.1

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

Am migrating my ember app to version 1.10.1 which is running fine in ember 1.9.1. While migrating am getting error saying "this.merge is not a function". My **emberTemplates** options looks something like

```
 emberTemplates: {
              options: {
                      templateCompilerPath: 'bower_components/ember/ember-template-compiler.js',
                      handlebarsPath: 'node_modules/handlebars/dist/handlebars.js',
                      templateNamespace: 'HTMLBars',
                      templateBasePath: /app\/templates\//
              }
 }
```

Any help in fixing this issue?

Comment: From which code `this.merge` error is coming?

Comment: templates.js. But never mind. Issue was resolved, if the handlbars.js and ember-template-compiler.js were included from vendor folder.